# Suppress ANSI codes while logging to file - python logging module

Tags: python, logging

Using below python code snippet to log the output to screen and log file. But when ANSI escape codes are used to highlight few lines as shown below it prints pretty in screen but in the log file text gets scrambled due to ANSI escape codes.

```
logger.info("\033[0;30;47m-\033[00m" * 10)
```

In log file it includes ANSI escape codes as shown below.

2017-05-07 02:28:52,360 INFO    ^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^[[00m^[[0;30;47m-^

```
def initialize_logging(options):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s\t%(message)s')
    level = logging.__dict__.get(options.loglevel.upper(),logging.DEBUG)
    logger.setLevel(level)

    if not options.quiet:
        hdlr = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
        hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(hdlr)

    logfile = options.logfile
    if options.clean and os.path.isfile(logfile):
        os.remove(logfile)
    hdlr2 = logging.FileHandler(logfile)
    hdlr2.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(hdlr2)

    return logger
```

How can I avoid ANSI escape codes only while logging into log file ? Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: I'm going to say: don't use these escape codes. Not all terminals will obey them, so there's no guarantee that even for console output, they work.

Comment: Thanks @Evert for the caution in using escape codes. It's working fine for my terminal and I do not have requirement to make it work for all the terminal types. Only worry is about removing escape codes while logging into log file.

Comment: What if someone redirects stdout to a file, to inspect it in a text editor; or pipes the log output through less? You run into the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the possibility of output getting messed due to bad practice of including escape codes directly. Please let me know what should be the best way in highlighting the output on console but not in the log file. This script output will not be used for any other means but log file will be inspected by the user and thus I need to remove these escape codes from log file. Please help.

Comment: Why (and what) precisely do you want to highlight (in) your log messages? That'll be important to answer the question you asked in your last comment.

Comment: Basically highlighting is for heading of output but not for any of the other log message, since this script will output lot of messages it is convenient to highlight the heading and sub-heading accordingly.

Comment: Log messages are usually one or two lines long; certainly not with headings and sub-headings.

Comment: You may have a look at various simple mark-up languages, what they use. For example, Markdown uses the '#' character for a heading, and then '##' for a sub-heading.

Comment: Finally, consider the following view: log messages are to be machine parsable, while fancier output (for a human) should be done using `print()`. The machine-parsable part would also be why a log-message should be one line.

Comment: Finally, you can of course just let the escape codes be, and simply run `sed` or some other replacement tool to clean up the final log file.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to remove these ansi codes within the python program while logging into log file without using OS level commands like sed?

Answer (score 0):

Bear with me, as I'm new to this and I'm not sure what the context of your code snippet is.  So, forgive me if this isn't helpful, but since you aren't using any formatters, can't you just log the raw string?

```
logger.info(r"\033[0;30;47m-\033[00m" * 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. If I use raw string then it just prints the raw message having ansi codes on console and in the log file as well. My issue is to disable ansi codes in log file but not in console as messages in log file getting messed with these ansi codes.